# what the accuracy of watson mandarin speech-to-text?

Tags: speech-recognition, ibm-watson, watson

I have tried to recognize the voice from wechat, but it turns out that the accuracy is very low, the Watson can only transcript very few or none of the content, so as a native Chinese, I believe my pronunciation is very good. For example, I say "the weather is good today", it just transcript nothing I wonder what is the accuracy of Mandarin speech-to-test

Answer (score 1):

There are no hard numbers on accuracy as it depends on many variables. IBM publishes a list of options though to improve the speech to text service accuracy here:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/faq.html#accuracy